# https to http redirecting

Tags: http, redirect, https

I have a website and domain was like https://example.com. Now my domain is http://example.com. I don't want want to remove SSL certificate I will renew it after 4-5 days. So till the time how can I redirect the user from my https to http?

I tried some code in htaccess but it's not working. I am using GoDaddy hosting.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: You can see this post http://dotnet4hosting.asphostportal.com/post/ASPNET-Hosting-How-to-Setup-URL-Redirection.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I haven't checked your answer. I got an answer after 6 months. Now I am using https.   I will refer your answer in the future.